# Joining two dataframes with messy column names in R

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

Given these exemplary datasets (1 and 2) :

**How can I merge each dataset (1 and 2) 
with the `codes` dataset so that names `codes$id` is mapped (sync'd ?) to `colnames` of
`dataset1` and `dataset2` where they match.**

`codes` is a data object  describing measurement stations.
`dataset1` and `dataset2` are measurements from some stations with a messy column naming - there is no actual pattern, except the "station`#`" part.

```
codes<- data.frame(
      id=c("MotherStation", "station2", "station3",
           "station4", "stationFive", "station6"),
      id2=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"),
      var1= seq(1:6),
      var2= seq(1:6))

dataset1 <- data.frame("291_hhaMotherStation_1g44" = rnorm(6), 
                        "143_wwaStation4_1d21"=rnorm(6))

dataset2 <- data.frame("143_wwaStation4_1d21" = rnorm(6), 
                        "station2WWa" = rnorm(6), 
                        "KrkStation6"=rnorm(6))
```

The result I'm looking for is this:

```
newData1 <- data.frame(MotherStation = dataset1$X291_hhaMotherStation_1g44,
                       station4 = dataset1$X143_wwaStation4_1d21)

newData2 <- data.frame(station4 = dataset2$X143_wwaStation4_1d21,
                       station2 = dataset2$station2WWa,
                       station6 = dataset2$KrkStation6)
```

I do feel, that a mix of `dplyr` `join`s and some strings matching with RegEx can get me there, but I'm stuck (it happens almost every time RegEx is involved).

EDIT: After reading [Jennifer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48157484/6925293) answer, I modified my exemplary code to match a more general case, where `id`s in `codes` dataframe not necessarily are identified by a unique number glued to `station`, but can actually be represented by strings only.

Comment: Is the `newData` also updated?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. `newData`  rows are the same is `dataset` rows. `newData` columns have names, mapped from `id` from `codes` where they matched. Unmatched columns retain their original name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work - first sub out everything not in the `id` column, then replace it with the exact string (because upper/lowercase is irregular)

```
dfs <- list(dataset1, dataset2)


out <-  lapply(dfs, function(x) {
  colnames(x) <- gsub(paste(".*(", paste(codes$id, collapse = "|"), ").*", sep = ""), 
       "\\1", colnames(x), perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
  colnames(x) <- sapply(colnames(x), function(y) as.character(codes$id[tolower(codes$id) == tolower(y)]))
  return(x)
})

> all.equal(out[[1]], newData1)
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(out[[2]], newData2)
[1] TRUE
```

and joining:

```
library(tidyverse)
do.call(full_join, out)
```

Comment: thanks! actually only the `gsub(...)` part is enough. I just tested in on real data and it does what I needed. Clearly `gsub` and regular expressions are things I must revist and finally learn.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very kludgy solution. I'm sure there's a prettier way to do this that eliminates the loop, but this should get you where you want to go, at least.

This standardizes the names across both datasets.

```
rename_col <- function(code, dataset){
  index <- grep(code, names(dataset), ignore.case = TRUE)
  names(dataset)[index] <- code
  return(dataset)
}

for(i in seq_len(nrow(codes))){
  dataset1 <- rename_col(codes[i, "id"], dataset1)
  dataset2 <- rename_col(codes[i, "id"], dataset2)
}
```

From there, you should be able to just do a full join.

```
full_join(dataset1, dataset2)
```

Comment: Jennifer: this gave me columns named by number only . In `dataset1` I get columns: `1` and `4` while I'm expecting `station1` `station4` - or what ever the code from `codes` is. Also, this function fails when `station1` is called `stationOne`. The goal here is to match whatever code there is in `codes`. Thanks for helping anyway :)

Comment: I'm not sure why you would get 1 and 4. I get station1 and station4. Make sure the `code` argument in the function is set to the variable you want to use for renaming - it was `id` in your example code.

You're right. It will only work with whatever is in your `codes` table. `stationOne` is not the same string as `station1`, so that's going to break. You might try using `gsub()` to change written numbers to numerals first.

Comment: Now I see, that I've simplified my example too much... The `id` column in `codes` object can actually consist of strings only. While your solution works for numbered id's I think I need a more general approach. I used numbers only to identify stations in my example as it was easier to type - and that's my mistake